# How to add a set of different values on a .each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I run the following but it's not doing why I would like to

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="removeJiku btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
<span  class="removeId" data-thisPostId="248"></span>

<button type="button" class="removeJiku btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
<span  class="removeId" data-thisPostId="242"></span>
```

JS

```
  $(".removeJiku").each(function(){
    var removeThisId = $(this).next(".removeId").attr("data-thisPostId");
    $("#usp-form-253 #usp-custom-3").attr("value", removeThisId.replace(/,/g, ", "));
  });
```

I need to add those values as my input value with comma separated in order to have:

```
<input type="text" id="usp-custom-3" value="242, 248">
```

Comment: Not really sure what you meant by "Provides different values: `242` and `248`". Can you add a working snippet?

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the attribute value first and then add it. But this is without regex

```
   $(".removeJiku").each(function(){
     var removeThisId = $(this).next(".removeId").attr("data-thisPostId");
  var existingValue = $("#usp-form-253 #usp-custom-3").attr("value");
  if(existingValue) {
    $("#usp-form-253 #usp-custom-3").attr("value", existingValue+','+removeThisId);
  } else{
     $("#usp-form-253 #usp-custom-3").attr("value",removeThisId);}  
});
```

Comment: Please accept the solution so that others also get benefit. Thanks

Comment: I was just awaiting to let me to

Answer (score 1):

you can store it in an string var before you put in input field.. without using regular expression

```
var strval= "";
var counter = 0;
$(".removeJiku").each(function(){
    var removeThisId = $(this).next(".removeId").attr("data-thisPostId");
     strval += (counter > 0 ? ", " : "") + removeThisId;
     counter++;
});
$("#usp-form-253 #usp-custom-3").val(strval);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$().each` has two default variables `index` and `element`

compare if `(index+1)` equals to `$('.removeJiku').length` to determine add comma or not
(index starts from 0)

```js
$(".removeJiku").each(function(index, element) {
    var removeThisId = $(this).next(".removeId").attr('data-thisPostId');
    var comma = (index+1) == $(".removeJiku").length ? "" : ", ";
    var value = $("#usp-custom-3").val() + removeThisId + comma;
    $("#usp-custom-3").val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="removeJiku btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
<span class="removeId" data-thisPostId="248"></span>

<button type="button" class="removeJiku btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
<span class="removeId" data-thisPostId="242"></span>
<input type="text" id="usp-custom-3" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make this very short and clean with `.map().toArray().join()`.

```js
$("#usp-custom-3").val(
  $(".removeJiku + .removeId").map((i, el) => $(el).attr("data-thisPostId"))
                              .toArray()
                              .join(", ")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="removeJiku btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
<span class="removeId" data-thisPostId="248"></span>

<button type="button" class="removeJiku btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
<span class="removeId" data-thisPostId="242"></span>

<input type="text" id="usp-custom-3" value="">
```

---

Or without jQuery:

```js
document.querySelector("#usp-custom-3").value =
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".removeJiku + .removeId")]
     .map(el => el.dataset.thispostid)
     .join(", ");
```

```html
<button type="button" class="removeJiku btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
<span class="removeId" data-thisPostId="248"></span>

<button type="button" class="removeJiku btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
<span class="removeId" data-thisPostId="242"></span>

<input type="text" id="usp-custom-3" value="">
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I really need to better look into `.map()`, i get across countless of times when I need it but I didn't understand it yet

Comment: You're welcome. The `.map()` is actually very simple. You use it when you have an array of items, and from that you want to make a new array of new items. So here we have a list of elements, and we want to end up with a list of their `data-thisPostId` value. So we use map, the callback is invoked on each element, and we return the element's `data-thisPostId`, which goes into the new array.

Comment: i see, so we basically use `.map()` to sort of loop each of them, then we send the to an array with `.toArray()` and finally we use `.join(", ")` to add them as comma separated list. Literally we could say `.map()` functions kind of as `.each()` or a for loop does, right? Thank you

Comment: Yes, `.map()` is a loop like `each`, the difference being that you return a value *(the data attribute in this case)* on every iteration to be put into the new array. The `.toArray()` is needed to convert the jQuery object to an actual array so you can call `.join()`.

Comment: Excellent, got it